# Error bluetooth with systemtcl

Tags: linux, bash, python, bluetooth, centos-7

I am trying to create a custom script, which has to run automatically during boot.
The custom script is running a python script which is using bluetooth. 
When I run this following line :

```
systemctl start myCustomService.service
```

The script works perfectly !

However when I reboot the computer, I have this following error :

> [localhost]# systemctl status myCustomService.service -l
>
> myCustomService.service.service - MycustomScript program
>
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myCustomService.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-21 15:03:38 CET; 1min 39s ago
>     Process: 821 ExecStart=/.../mycustomScript.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>    Main PID: 821 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: File "main.py", line 69, in
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: profiles=[SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE],
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 266, in advertise_service
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: raise BluetoothError (*e.args)
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error no advertisable device.
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[1]: sample.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[1]: Unit sample.service entered failed state.
>
> Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[1]: sample.service failed.

My service is running after bluetooth services, hence, I don't understand why I have this error.

PS : I am using Centos 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python script exits with an error on line 266. Systemd has no idea why it happened but gives you the actual program output in error messages:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 266, in advertise_service
raise BluetoothError (*e.args)

Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[821]: bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error no advertisable device.

Feb 21 15:03:38 localhost mycustomScript.sh[1]: sample.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

A dirty workaround in such situations is to add

```
ExecStartPre=bash -c "sleep 30"
```

or as many seconds as you think your system needs to start bluetooth devices

Comment: The problem is coming from the bluetooth device, which is not activated when my script starts, however, I am using **Requires** and **After** to wait for the bluetooth activation. But it stills doesn't work

Comment: I solved it ! I added this command on my bash script : "
hciconfig hci0 
piscan sleep 30"
Quite dirty workaround but... I didn't find something else

Comment: Does not really matter where you pause it )